# How to start Intent from OneSignal HandleNotificationOpened in Visual Studio with Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, onesignal

I try to use OneSignal in Android app, created with VS with Xamarin (not Xamarin Forms). It works fine, but I can't implement some function. App can get 3 different types of push notification. When app gets 1-st type, it changes global variable only. When app gets 2-nd and 3-rd, it needs to start specific intent. In iOS app I found the solution, but in Android I found solution only for closed app but not for app in background. I can't start intent right from "HandleNotificationOpened" function. Can anybody help me with this problem.
Here the code:

```
public class SplashActivity : Activity{
    static bool isNotify=false;
    static string messageAct = "";
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        OneSignal.Current.StartInit("mykey")
            .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
            .HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened)
            .EndInit();
        OneSignal.Current.IdsAvailable(IdsAvailable);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Intent notificationIntent;
        if(isNotify){
            if(messageAct="1"){
                notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ProfileActivity));
            }
            if(messageAct="2"){
                notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationsActivity));
            }
            else{
                notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            }
        }
        else{
            notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        }
        StartActivity(notificationIntent);
    }
    private static void HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
    {
        OSNotificationPayload payload = result.notification.payload;
        Dictionary<string, object> additionalData = payload.additionalData;
        string message = payload.body;
        if (additionalData != null)
        {
            isNotify = true;
            if (additionalData.ContainsKey("act"))
            {
                messageAct = additionalData["act"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like It need to add OneSignal Init and HandleNotificationOpen to each Activity.

Another solution, as [Joe Lv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8632294/joe-lv) suggests, to create BaseActivity class, extends Activity, add OneSignal Init and HandleNotificationOpen in this class and use it instead Activity for other Activities in app. Look like that:

```
public class BaseActivity : Activity{
        static bool isNotify=false;
        static string messageAct = "";
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            OneSignal.Current.StartInit("mykey")
                .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
                .HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened)
                .EndInit();
            OneSignal.Current.IdsAvailable(IdsAvailable);
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Intent notificationIntent;
            if(isNotify){
                if(messageAct="1"){
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ProfileActivity));
                }
                if(messageAct="2"){
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationsActivity));
                }
                else{
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                }
            }
            else{
                notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            }
            StartActivity(notificationIntent);
        }
        private static void HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
        {
            OSNotificationPayload payload = result.notification.payload;
            Dictionary<string, object> additionalData = payload.additionalData;
            string message = payload.body;
            if (additionalData != null)
            {
                isNotify = true;
                if (additionalData.ContainsKey("act"))
                {
                    messageAct = additionalData["act"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ActivityOne : BaseActivity{
        // do ActivityOne stuff
    }


    public class ActivityTwo : BaseActivity{
        // do ActivityTwo stuff
    }
```

Comment: So, is this the solution for your question?

Comment: @JoeLv Well, it works, so yes. But I'm not sure, that this solution is optimal. Unfortunately I haven't time to find better way.

Comment: Why not create a `BaseActivity` and you just need add OneSignal Init and HandleNotificationOpen in the `BaseActivity`, or you can try do this in your `Application` class.

Comment: @JoeLv Sorry, don't understand, what do you mean. What BaseActivity?

Comment: You can create a `BaseActivity` which will be extended by others `Activity`, in the `BaseActivity` you can do something which will be done in every `Activity`.

Comment: @JoeLv System sad, I'll can do it only tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, please remember it.